# Parse file by user / host / workspace sum results

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that was generated by another person's script that looks like this: (highly truncated example)

```
Usage by user / host / workspace directory:

adallman:
  sideshow:
    bob               12065 MB
    mel                 488 MB
  simpsons:
    bart              32965 MB
afkham:
  simpsons:
    lisa             102466 MB
agnewjo:
  flanders:
    ned               70847 MB
    rod                2657 MB
ahoang:
  flanders:
    rod                2896 MB
akrishna:
  flanders:
    ned                3310 MB
  moes:
    barney             1850 MB
    carl              15674 MB
    lenny             10723 MB
  sideshow:
    bob                   0 MB
    mel              101700 MB
  simpsons:
    bart                  0 MB
    lisa                  0 MB
```

so in other words user is in the file above we can interpret what we see as i.e..,

```
User:
  Host:
    Workspace: <size on that workspace MB>
```

I'd like the output to look like this: (truncated)

```
adallman: <total in GB>
  afkham: <total in GB>
 agnewjo: <total in GB>
  ahoang: <total in GB>
```

And I just want to sum the total of each user.

Keeping in mind I can sum created a user list like this:

```
ypcat passwd | cut -d: -f1 > valid_users
```

and get back something like this: (truncated)

```
zahrobsk
mylonopo
alindema
sutterk
sstslim
wleung
pazgil
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the exact output that you are expecting for the input you have shown.

Comment: What does `<username>` consist of ?

Comment: In the example above the user names are not indented, the hostnames are indented by 2, and the workspaces on those hosts are indented further still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ awk '!/^ / {name=$1; next} NF==3{a[name]+=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]/1024, "GB"}' file
adallman: 44.4512 GB
ahoang: 2.82812 GB
afkham: 100.064 GB
akrishna: 130.134 GB
agnewjo: 71.7812 GB
```

#### Explanation

- It gets as username those lines not starting with space.
- For all of them, then it keeps adding the value in the 2nd column.
- Finally it prints the result divided by 1024, to represent GB.

Comment: Awesome I lost my connection on the VPN I'll try it when I get back on thanks :)

Comment: If I do an awk '{print $2}' | sort -n -r it will sort the sizes but it won't keep the users together with their sizes. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: Also @BrianBills pipe it into `| sort -nrk2`

Comment: Now what if I want to filter for any user over 100GB

Comment: I think I found the answer to my last question | awk 'int($2)>=100'

Comment: Now that I have my results do you know how to add a comma between the first and second column so I can export this to a csv file?

Comment: @BrianBills you can for example use `awk '!/^ / {sub(":","",$1); name=$1; next} NF==3{a[name]+=$2} END {for (i in a) printf "%s,%sGB\n", i, a[i]/1024}' file`.

Comment: That worked but now my  | awk 'int($2)>=100' yields nothing. But thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: Can I do it in reverse order? In other words run your first command | sort the results | filter for > 100GB, and then add the commas?

Comment: @BrianBills You can use as many possibilities as you want. Try to define one :D For your last question, I would do `awk '...' file | sort -t, -rnk2 | awk -F, '$2+0>100'`

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution (reading the file from *stdin*):

```
#!/bin/bash

valid_users=$( ypcat passwd | cut -d: -f1 )

declare -A sizes

while read username size foo
do
  if [ "$foo" = "MB" ]
  then
    let sizes[$username]=$(( sizes[$username] + $size ))
  fi
done

for i in $valid_users
do
  GB=$(( ${sizes[$i]:-0} / 1024 ))
  echo "$i: $GB"
done
```

Comment: I lost my connection on the VPN I'll try it when I get back on thanks :)

Comment: This one might work but the script was taking a long time and even though I ran it with -x it seemed hung after it went through the valid user list. Maybe it was just doing stuff and I should have waited. I'll leave this one running over night.